# query taking too long, while split it to two queries taking 0.2 sec

Tags: mysql, performance, join

i have the current query:

```
select m.id, ms.severity, ms.risk_score, count(distinct si.id), boarding_date_tbl.boarding_date
from merchant m
join merchant_has_scan ms on m.last_scan_completed_id = ms.id
join scan_item si on si.merchant_has_scan_id = ms.id and si.is_registered = true
join (select m.id merchant_id, min(s_for_boarding.scan_date) boarding_date
    from merchant m
    left join merchant_has_scan ms on m.id = ms.merchant_id
    left join scan s_for_boarding on s_for_boarding.id = ms.scan_id and s_for_boarding.scan_type = 1
    group by m.id) boarding_date_tbl on boarding_date_tbl.merchant_id = m.id
group by m.id
limit 100;
```

when i run it on big scheme (about 2mil "merchant") it takes more then 20 sec.
but if i'll split it to:

```
select m.legal_name, m.unique_id, m.merchant_status, s_for_boarding.scan_date
from merchant m
join merchant_has_scan ms on m.id = ms.merchant_id
join scan s_for_boarding on s_for_boarding.id = ms.scan_id and s_for_boarding.scan_type = 1
group by m.id
limit 100;
```

and

```
select m.id, ms.severity, ms.risk_score, count(distinct si.id)
from merchant m
join merchant_has_scan ms on m.last_scan_completed_id = ms.id
join scan_item si on si.merchant_has_scan_id = ms.id and si.is_registered = true

group by m.id
limit 100;
```

both will take about 0.1 sec
the reason for that is clear, the low limit means it doesn't need to do much to get the first 100. it is also clear that the inner select cause the first query to run as much as it does. 
my question is there a way to do the inner select only on the relevant merchants and not on the entire table?

---

### Update

making a `left join` instead of a `join` before the inner query help reduce it to 6 sec, but it still a lot more then what i can get if i do 2 queries

---

### UPDATE 2

create table for merchant:

```
CREATE TABLE `merchant` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_scan_completed_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9lhkm7tb4bt87qy4j3fjayec5` FOREIGN KEY (`last_scan_completed_id`) REFERENCES `merchant_has_scan` (`id`)
)
```

merchant_has_scan:

```
CREATE TABLE `merchant_has_scan` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `merchant_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `risk_score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scan_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_merchant_id` (`scan_id`,`merchant_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_3d8f81ts5wj2u99ddhinfc1jp` FOREIGN KEY (`scan_id`) REFERENCES `scan` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_e7fhioqt9b9rp9uhvcjnk31qe` FOREIGN KEY (`merchant_id`) REFERENCES `merchant` (`id`)
)
```

scan_item:

```
CREATE TABLE `scan_item` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `is_registered` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `merchant_has_scan_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_avcc5q3hkehgreivwhoc5h7rb` FOREIGN KEY (`merchant_has_scan_id`) REFERENCES `merchant_has_scan` (`id`)
)
```

scan:

```
CREATE TABLE `scan` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `scan_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `scan_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and the explain:

[image]

Comment: It would be nice you to post tables schema

Comment: @tvelykyy it a bit big, and i'm not sure if it will be helpful, but i can do it if it helps

Comment: @tvelykyy added explain and create statement

Answer (score 0):

- You don't have the latest version of MySQL, which would be able to create an index for the derived table.  (What version are you running?)
- The "derived table" (the subquery) will be the first table in the `EXPLAIN` because, well, it has to be.
- `merchant_has_scan` is a many:many table, but without the optimization tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) -- fixing this may be the biggest factor in speeding it up.  Caveat:  The tips suggest getting rid of `id`, but you seem to have a use for `id`, so keep it.
- The `COUNT(DISTINCT si.id)` and `JOIN si...` can be replaced by `( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM scan_item WHERE ...)`, thereby eliminating one of the `JOINs` and possibly diminishing the [*Explode-Implode*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#explode_implode) .
- `LEFT JOIN` -- are you sometimes expecting to  get `NULL` for `boarding_date`?  If not, please use `JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`.  (It is better to state your intention than to leave the query open to multiple interpretations.)
- If you can remove the `LEFTs`, then since `m.id` and `merchant_id` are specified to be equal, why list them both in the `SELECT`?  (This is a confusion factor, not a speed question).
- You say you split it into two -- but you did not.  You added `LIMIT 100` to the inner query when you pulled it out.  If you need that, add it to the derived table, too.  Then you *may* be able to remove `GROUP BY m.id LIMIT 100` from the outer query.

Comment: added explain and create statement.
using MYSQL 5.7